# Annoying mysql update query problem

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to update using mysql_query in php and it gives me this error:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'read='1' WHERE id='14'' at line 1
```

I've been looking at my query for about 10 minutes now and I cant find whats wrong with it. Here it is:

```
    if ($row['read'] == 0) {
        mysql_query("UPDATE mail SET read='1' WHERE id='$mailid'") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Do anyone see where the error is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`read` is a reserved word.

Enclose it into the backticks:

```
UPDATE mail SET `read`='1' WHERE id='$mailid'
```

Comment: @Kraffs Then you should set this answer as the good one and click the _tick_ on the left of this answer.

Comment: Chouchenos I know :D. But it forces me to wait 10 minutes to accept an answer.

Answer (score 2):

How about...

```
"UPDATE `mail` SET `read`='1' WHERE `id`='".$mailid."'"
```

Comment: Thanks, and ten seconds earlier! Though he made the specific point re: the reserved word, and thats the important thing, see here for ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 2):

`read` is a reserved word. You need to use backticks ` around read.